# Should I give credits to Stack Overflow if 30% of my website basecode comes from it?

Tags: discussion, legal, attribution, licensing, creative-commons

I'm always looking answer to my problems on Stack Overflow, should I give credits to it?

Answer (score 8):

Within the codebase: The license on SO is currently [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). That may or may not be [changing sometime this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1). See that link for a (long) discussion of aspects of that (both attribution and license).

In terms of something visible to your visitors, there's no requirement that you give credit publicly, but there's also no harm in a small thing in the footer or the About Us or something just saying thanks to the SO community.